# How to get the offset time when the timezone is known using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

Is there a way to know the offset time (how much ahead or behind the UTC/GMT), if I have the timezone value (for example 'America/Chicago') in momentjs or some other library in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the `utcOffset`.

```js
const offset = moment().tz('America/Chicago').utcOffset();

console.log(`Offset in hours: ${offset / 60}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```